# PDFCrowd 'Missing artifact'

Tags: java, maven, pdf-generation

I am trying to convert an html file to PDF using PDFCrowd. It is working fine in normal web project in Eclipse, but I face a problem when running the same code in a Maven project. `pom.xml` is giving 'Missing artifact' message.

Here's the dependency from my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.pdfcrowd</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfcrowd</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: http://pdfcrowd.com/web-html-to-pdf-java/#install

Comment: Where did you get this dependency xml from?

Comment: https://github.com/Mashape/MVNRepo
from above link i got the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I think the web repository no pdfcrowd. So you have to install the jar to your local m2 folder.

Just like below:

> > mvn install:install-file -Dfile=pdfcrowd.jar -DgroupId=com.pdfcrowd -DartifactId=pdfcrowd -Dversion=2.6 -Dpackaging=jar

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pdfcrowd</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfcrowd</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```